# Cant able to use wget or curl in ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: 20.04, ssl, error-handling, wget, curl

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
--2022-07-06 09:24:21--  https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
Resolving repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)... 104.16.130.3, 104.16.131.3, 2606:4700::6810:8303, ...
Connecting to repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)|104.16.130.3|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
root@gcba-lambda-01:/apps# curl https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to repo.anaconda.com:443
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the same URLs with a browser, from the same machine? Maybe something in the network is blocking HTTPS connections?

Comment: Try using the verbose options and then the `--insecure` option of curl

Comment: Tried curl --insecure and wget --no-check-certificate also, doesn't worked out

Comment: It worked the first time I tried with `wget` when I tried in my Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.4 LTS. Are you behind a VPN or some special firewall? Is your Ubuntu up to date? Or maybe there was a temporary error?

Comment: I have disabled the firewall and stopped it to and ubuntu is up to date